# OAuthException 200 facebook sdk wp8

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, windows-phone-8, facebook-sdk-3.0

`(OAuthException - #200) (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action` when post on facebook by through winows phone 8 code:

```
dynamic fbPostTaskResult = await instance.PostTaskAsync("me/feed", postParams);
```

permessions add in 
`session = await App.FacebookSessionClient.LoginAsync("user_about_me,read_stream,publish_actions");`

Debug access token on facebook app display

App ID  --
User ID --
Issued  1409307661 
Expires 1414491661 
Valid   True
Origin  Mobile Web Faceweb 
Scopes  public_profile

Comment: in facebook App Domains field fill necessary or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve by adding permession **publish_action** and provide description and detail on **app status & review**